# NoMethodError: undefined method `create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting learning ruby and starting to loving it, but I have a problem that I couldn't solve by myself.

I just cannot use a created model to find or create data into the db, getting the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'create' for Stuff:Module`

The model class it's simple:

```
class Stuff < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.18'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Migration file:

```
class Stuff < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :stuffs do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
    add_index :stuffs, :id
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class StuffsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_stuffs, :only => [:index, :show]
  before_action :validate_params, :only => [:create]

  def get_stuffs
    @stuffs = []
  end

  def show

  end

  def index

  end

  def create
    Stuff.create(params[:name])
  end

  private

  def validate_params
    params.require(:name)
  end
end
```

This is not just for the *create* method but for any other one, like *find*, *first* or *all*.

I get this error calling any method from controller, but also from, for example, `seed.rb`.

I'm sure this it's a silly newbie question, but I can't figure out how to fix this...

Thank you!

Comment: Note that the error message says `Stuff:Module`, not `Stuff:Class` - do you have a `Stuff` module in addition to your class?

Comment: I did not created any module for that class, rails tutorial didn't mentioned I had to, have I?

Comment: When do you get the error? Are you able to create a Stuff object in rails console? If you can't create stuff objects in the console, post the contents of the migration file for the stuff table. Also, post the StuffController.

Comment: I get the error from a controller method, executing rake db:seed, or calling Stuff.create from console. I updated the post with the controller and migration file.

Comment: Somewhere you've defined `Stuff` strangely, and seemingly more than once. For one, your migration shouldn't include `class Stuff`, it should be `class CreateStuffs`. Search your code for all occurrences of `Stuff` and see where else you might be redeclaring it, then eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: @frostering - Do you happen to have a folder called stuff in your application?

Comment: @Kristján I searched for any redeclaration, but couldn't find anything. I fixed the migration file, but that isn't the problem.

Comment: @BroiSatse Yes I do. I have a stuff.rb under /app/models/stuff/stuff.rb

Comment: You need to move it out of that folder. Rails creates a module for each folder existing in a load path. Another option is to scope your model as `Stuff::Stuff`

Comment: Thank you @BroiSatse, that solved the issue. I thought that I could use the same hierarchy name for models folder, I like the same structure for both controller and models folder. Anyway, I'll deal with it. If you provide an answer I'll gladly accept it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this is caused by Rails' autoloading feature. In general, Rails does not load all your classes when the application starts, so `Stuff` does not exist when your application boots. Try this in your console:

```
Object.constants.include? :Stuff #=> false
```

When Ruby reaches a constant in your code, it starts a process called constant lookup. It is quite complex, so I'll skip it for now. The important thing is that if Ruby fails to find a constant, Rails will kick in with it's `constant_missing` magic and search your `load_path` for a file with a name that matches your constant, so `Stuff` is expected to be defined in the `stuff.rb` file directly in your `load_path`.

By default `load_path` includes all the subfolders in your `app` folder, so it will only be looking for `stuff.rb` directly in one of those subfolders.

Things are slightly different when a constant resides within another module. If you're trying to load constant `A::B`, it will first need to load module `A` and then class `A::B` from file`a/b.rb`. To save us from creating dummy files with empty modules, Rails will resolve `A` to be a new blank module if it finds the `a` folder but fails to find an `a.rb` file.

That is exactly what happened here. When you called the `Stuff` constant, which was not yet defined, it was looking for the `stuff.rb` file in your app folder. Since it didn't find it, but there was a `stuff` folder, Rails generated a blank module Stuff.

One possible fix, just move your `stuff.rb` file out of the stuff folder and all should work.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it's good to name your create migration like 
`CreateStuff`, check out [rails migration naming convention](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)